# Stopping a service in C# without permission elevation

Tags: c#, windows-services, uac

I need to beable to shut a service down via an exe that can be called from third party software so I thought I would whip a quick solution up using C#.

I am trying to use the following code that I found online to stop a service but it wont work unless I run the exe as administrator (which ideally I dont want to have to do as I am trying to get this as a slick )

```
public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        service.MachineName = ".";
        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
        }
        catch
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Is there a way around needing elevation?

Comment: I don't think you can stop a windows service unless the service is running under the same account.

Comment: Wouldn't that trick defeat the purpose of privileges and access rights. What virus would *not* utilize this trick?

Comment: There is no way around that except by hacking the system/exploiting some bug... => NO!

Comment: Good points everybody - hadn't thought about it from that point of view.  I am the domain admin so can I pass in security credentials somehow instead?

Comment: An eaiser solution might be to get the users permission to run as admin on startup.  Is that an easy function on setup?

Answer (score 4):

There are access control lists on the individual services. You can grant rights to specific users or groups to be able to shut down/starup a specific service. You can get a cmd line tool "subinacl" to set the acl from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23510
Note that you can grant rights to shutdown a service, without granting rights to query the service configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way: What point would the whole security thing be, if there were ways around it?

So, no. Unless the service is running under the same account, you shouldn't be allowed to stop it.

The first thing I'd do if I were a virus? Stop the virus scanning service using "a way around needing elevation".

Answer (score 1):

You could install your own 'Stopper-Service' that communicates with an dedicated .exe file or any application, which knows how to communicate with that service (e.g. via named pipes).

So all your app/.exe does is signaling this service, that it has to stop/restart etc. a specific service.

If you only want to stop your own service(s), you could consider integrating such messaging functionality, so you would be able to control it without admin privileges.

Of course you would have to implement adequate security mechanisms, to ensure, only authorized apps may gain control.

Hope this helps.